# Banned for a month from reviewing because of one mistake

Tags: discussion, support, triage, review-suspension

I was in the flow of reviewing posts and have just had this today:

> Your review on [triage/26473900](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26473900) wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing"
> option should only be used when other community users (like you) are
> able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better
> shape. If a question can be closed or can only be improved/clarified
> by the question asker, please use the "Unsalvageable" option instead.
> If in doubt always use the "Skip" option. For more information, see
> Getting banned from Triage reviews and How does the Triage queue
> work?.
>
> Come back on Jul 24 at 7:08 to continue reviewing.

On reading a few support articles on here I get it, I was using the Requires Editing completely wrong.

I was quite enjoying carrying out Triage and first post reviews as I was learning a lot in the process, so just want to know how to get back to doing it again sooner instead of having to wait a month?

Upon reading about this, I realise it was unsalvageable.

"Requires editing" is for when another SO'er could easily modify to make more sense or improve formatting, (something which I actually enjoy doing).

To be fair I should have just read the docs more carefully in the first place before jumping into the whole reviewing thing. Kinda shot myself in the foot by not doing what I've been telling others to do with the whole, "Learn how to ask " link!

Comment: That's why I stopped triage, SE claims it needs to be fixed.

Comment: So what did you do wrong and what have you learned after reading the meta posts? What should the preferred action be on post like that? Do know there is also a [Skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) option that doesn't carry shame nor penalty when used frequently.

Comment: Mistake [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26475249), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26474705), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26475300), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26458987), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26458151).....

Comment: @rene It was unsalvageable. "Requires editing" is for when another SO'er could easily modify to make more sense or improve formatting, (something which I actually enjoy doing). Tbf I should have just read the docs more carefully in the first place before jumping into the whole reviewing thing. Kinda shot myself in the foot by not doing what I've been telling others to do with the whole, "Learn how to ask " link!

Comment: @Nick THey weren't mentioned in the ban text, but as mentioned in question, realised upon reading that I'd been doing it all wrong from the start and should have read docs better. I can probably guarantee that you'll find more from me from when I started. Lesson learnt though.

Comment: That is useful info that should go into your question as "evidence". If a mod comes across this meta posts and reviews what you claim to have learned they might decide to lift the ban early.

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester Yes, it's a lot of effort for mods to go through linking all of them, so the ban comment only contains 1. But if you go through your other reviews looking at ones that are now closed it should give you some idea of which ones were also mistakes. We do want you to review, so the links are more to provide you with more context and to help you to learn.

Comment: @Nick Yeah I can imagine. I get it now though, I was just lazy by not reading the docs properly and just assumed Requires Editing was a bit more of a catchall over Unsalvageable which I thought would get the user punished for just asking a question in a bad way. Pretty much all of my Requires Editing would have been Unsalvageable, give or take a few. Hopefully a mod does see this all anyway as I want to get back on it!

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester If you haven't read it, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work) is probably the most important bit of information you'll find on triage

Comment: @Nick, just read it before, although I didn't know this "Know your judgment is **final** (no immediate undo possible) – except for Skip." need to go over it a couple more times I think!

Comment: *"To be fair I should have just read the docs more carefully in the first place before jumping into the whole reviewing thing"*. It pays to scour meta.so as well, there is a wealth of information in there that you will not find in the help center in so many words.

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester sounds like you're reviewing for the right reasons and reading and learning about where you've got stuff wrong so I've lifted the review ban so that after you've finished digesting all the info. you're ready to go.

Comment: @Jon It's saying I've been banned again for this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499966/403-response-in-vanilla-ajax-php-post-request. I promise you I didn't do that yesterday and still haven't worked up the courage to get back into it reviewing yet. Can you take a look when you get a moment please? Unless I've lost my mind this was done before me learning how to review properly!

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester umm yeah... you're unbanned again :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have made a very common mistake; that is why it needs to be fixed.

See, the "Requires Editing" button is when a post is editable by **you or another user other than the OP**.

That post is not detailed enough, only the OP can give more detail.

The reason this needs to be fixed is because there are a lot of questions that are like this, and when you click "Unsalvageable", you have to raise a flag. You only have 10 flags per day, which is why it needs to be fixed.

Comment: 10 flags is the default, you get an extra flag on each 10 helpful flags so with a bit of effort you reach in 6 to 8 weeks the point where you have more flags then allotted review tasks.

Comment: @rene Correct: I have 13 flags personally, but looking at the OP's number of flags, he would definetely have 10 flags. Even if you have 20 flags, you can't flag all the content out there, right?

Comment: @WaiHaLee That;s because there is so much bad content.

Comment: I have 100 post flags and 100 comnent flags, 50 close votes, 30 delete votes. 40 downvotes per day. I can spend them all, still leaves new LQ stuff around.

Comment: @rene Again, proves how much bad content there is.